# Matlab - text analytic toolbox

Tags: matlab, tags

I want to develop information retrieval system for Amharic language corpus but matlab don't read and display Ethiopic-Unicode characters neither in command line nor in editor window.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the lack of appropriate fonts. For example, if I have a pdf of Ethiopic-Unicode pdf file, the following MATLAB codes can read it,

```
filename = 'Amharic_sample.pdf';
str = extractFileText(filename);
```

but characters are garbled in MATLAB windows and are shown as white rectangles. After I installed Ethiopia Jiret [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Multilingual_support_(Ethiopic)), and change MATLAB's Desktop text font to Ethiopia Jiret in MATLAB Preferences, MATLAB shows these characters correctly.